# android app asks for OpencvManager installation even after including opencv sdk in project and adding dependency

Tags: android, opencv, dependencies

I have been trying to do this from past few days. Aim is to access android camera and stream frames on the screen using opencv library.

```
Opencv sdk version 4.3.0
Android Studio Version 3.6.3
```

I followed [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-opencv-android-library-on-android-studio-19794e220f3c) tutorial to get started. Initially I was unable to add the opencv library as module dependency to app. Later after spending a lot of time, using this [solution.](https://answers.opencv.org/question/222392/importing-opencv-4x-android-sdk-module-into-android-studio/) I can now add opencv library as module dependency.

Now the issue is, even after adding opencv library as module dependency, when the app runs it prompts to install `OpencvManager` app from play store.*(by the way, that app is not found on play store)*

[image: Prompt Image]

If anyone has a solution or any leads, to run the app `without installing OpencvManager`, I would be very grateful.

Source code is inspired(*or copied*) from this [sample project](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/android/tutorial-1-camerapreview).

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test_opencv">

<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus" android:required="false"/>

<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:opencv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/tutorial1_activity_java_surface_view"
    opencv:show_fps="true"
    opencv:camera_id="any" />

</FrameLayout>
```

> MainActivity.java, remove import statements for brevity

```
package com.example.test_opencv;

public class MainActivity extends CameraActivity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {
    private static final String TAG = "OCVSample::Activity";

    private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;
    private boolean              mIsJavaCamera = true;
    private MenuItem             mItemSwitchCamera = null;

    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
    };

    static {
        if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "open cv initialized");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "opec cv not initialized");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mOpenCvCameraView = findViewById(R.id.tutorial1_activity_java_surface_view);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Internal OpenCV library not found");
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
        mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
    }
   enter image description here }

    @Override
    protected List<? extends CameraBridgeViewBase> getCameraViewList() {
        return Collections.singletonList(mOpenCvCameraView);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {}

    public void onCameraViewStopped() {}

    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        return inputFrame.rgba();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just have followed [this](https://medium.com/beesightsoft/setup-opencv-android-without-install-opencv-manager-apk-bea6acf9e2c1) with the latest(like you) version of everything. And it's working! Enjoy!

I am giving my version of instructions thinking about if the link ever gets broken.

1. Download opencv sdk for android at: https://opencv.org/releases.html
2. Unzip opencv sdk and place it in the same root of sample project folder

   -> MyProjects

   ```
   ->OpenCV-android-sdk
   ->OpenCVSample
   ```
3. In your project (e.g. OpenCVSample), open settings.gradle file and add config below

   `def opencvsdk = '<path_to_opencv_android_sdk_rootdir>'
   include ':opencv'
   project(':opencv').projectDir = new File(opencvsdk + '/sdk')
   Example with my settings.gradle file
   include ':app'`

In my case:

```
rootProject.name='OpenCVSample'
include ':app'
def opencvsdk = '../OpenCV-android-sdk'
include ':opencv'
project(':opencv').projectDir = new File(opencvsdk + '/sdk')
```

4. In app/build.gradle, add opencv module to dependencies

   `implementation project(':opencv')`

Sync now and the environment is ready. After this I copied the manifest, layout and activity codes from your question and it ran exactly like what you wanted.